# Thumb swiper demo example not working - Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I'm trying to run the core demo example in the document, but it doesn't work. In the examples in the document, the currently active thumb swiper takes the swiper-slide-thumb-active class, but this is not the case for me. For me, it takes the swiper-slide-active class that is active in the thumb swiper. So my thumb swiper behaves like a normal swiper.
Version: swiper@11.0.5

Here is my code:

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiper,
  },
});
```

```
<div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>

<div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
     <img src="(here goes img link)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with adding this:

Swiper.use([Navigation, Thumbs]);